# Convert byte[] or object to GUID

Tags: c#, active-directory, guid

I assigned some value to object data type like,

```
object objData =dc.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["objectGUID"].Value;
```

this object retun the value like `{byte[16]}
    [0]: 145
    [1]: 104
    [2]: 117
    [3]: 139
    [4]: 124
    [5]: 15
    [6]: 255
    [7]: 68
    [8]: 142
    [9]: 159
    [10]: 208
    [11]: 102
    [12]: 148
    [13]: 157
    [14]: 179
    [15]: 75`

Then i casting this object to byte[], like

```
byte[] binaryData = objData as byte[];
```

It will also return like, 
 `{byte[16]}
    [0]: 145
    [1]: 104
    [2]: 117
    [3]: 139
    [4]: 124
    [5]: 15
    [6]: 255
    [7]: 68
    [8]: 142
    [9]: 159
    [10]: 208
    [11]: 102
    [12]: 148
    [13]: 157
    [14]: 179
    [15]: 75`

Then i convert the hex values from byte[] like,

```
string strHex = BitConverter.ToString(binaryData);
```

It will be return like `**91-68-75-8B-7C-0F-FF-44-8E-9F-D0-66-94-9D-B3-4B**`..
But i need the output like GUID format, How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

How about using the [`Guid` constructor which takes a byte array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3.aspx#Y0)?

```
Guid guid = new Guid(binaryData);
```

(You can then use `Guid.ToString()` to get it in text form if you need to.)

Comment: ,,, Thanks for your reply.. it's working... Is there anyway to convert GUID from object datatype?

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju: You should just cast, e.g. `new Guid((byte[]) objData)`

Comment: @Rab: I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, Guid(byte[]) generates a modified GUID, not the exact hexadecimal representation of the array. For example, for the following byte array [27,131,88,183,70,167,69,138,185,73,226,160,62,193,49,52] it generates " b758831b-a746-8a45-b949-e2a03ec13134" whereas it should generate " 1b8358b7-46a7-458a-b949-e2a03ec13134" (27 == 0x1b, 131 == 0x83, etc). Guid(string) works differently though. If you pass "1b8358b746a7458ab949e2a03ec13134" it uses the string "as is" and generates "1b8358b7-46a7-458a-b949-e2a03ec13134".

Comment: @evgenybf: That's just a matter of rearranging the bytes if you need to, which isn't terribly hard to do.

Answer (score 7):

```
byte[] binaryData = objData as byte[];
string strHex = BitConverter.ToString(binaryData);
Guid id = new Guid(strHex.Replace("-", ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

The long form would be ([enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#29)):

```
public static string ConvertGuidToOctectString(string objectGuid)
{
    System.Guid guid = new Guid(objectGuid);
    byte[] byteGuid = guid.ToByteArray();
    string queryGuid = "";
    foreach (byte b in byteGuid)
    {
        queryGuid += @"\" + b.ToString("x2");
    }
    return queryGuid;
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using exactly this for an ´LDAP´ query. Thanks. But is there no "official" .net framework method to get the octet representation?

Answer (score 0):

The `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` class has the property `Guid` for this purpose - no need to access the objectGUID attribute through `Properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Though the manual casting suggested above works, there's a way to do this automatically.

1. You can use the official SQLite provider instead of the one from Microsoft. Use its `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` to configure a Connection that understands your Guids as Guids:

```cs
var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source=./mydatabase.db") { BinaryGUID = true };
var connStr = builder.ToString();
return new SQLiteConnection(connStr);
```

Here's the official SQLite provider: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/

2. If using Dapper, you can have it automatically convert byte arrays to Guid using this class, which should be registered once as soon as your app starts:

```cs
public class GuidTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Guid>
{
    public override Guid Parse(object value)
    {
        var valueAsBytes = (byte[])value;
        return new Guid(valueAsBytes);
    }

    public override void SetValue(System.Data.IDbDataParameter parameter, Guid value)
    {
        var guidAsBytes = value.ToByteArray();
        parameter.Value = guidAsBytes;
    }
}

// And the registration in Startup.cs or equivalent:
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler<Guid>(new GuidTypeHandler());
```

Source: [Dapper Issue #718 - GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/718)