# System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher objectGUID value incorrect System.Byte[]

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have code that I have modified that I got from here: https://blog.schmijos.ch/2013/09/27/ad-export-with-get-qaduser-is-too-slow/

The code I have modified includes pagesize, so it can grab more than 1000 accounts. It changes the date values from some really big number to a readable date/time stamp. The entire modified code I have here...

```
function CreateQueriedCsvDataSheet
{
    $csvFileWithPath = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\testResults.csv'
    $DomainControlConnector = 'www.example.com'
    $DomainName = 'myDomain1'
    $domainUserProperties = @('sAMAccountName', 'msRTCSIP-UserEnabled', 'msRTCSIP-OptionFlags', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer', 
    'mail', 'msExchMasterAccountSid', 'homeMDB', 'proxyaddresses', 'legacyExchangeDN', 
    'lastLogonTimestamp', 'logonCount', 'lastLogoff', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet', 'userAccountControl', 'whenCreated', 'whenChanged', 'accountExpires', 
    'sn', 'givenName', 'displayName', 'distinguishedName', 'initials', 'l', 'st', 'street', 'title', 'description', 'postalCode', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'telephoneNumber', 'facsimileTelephoneNumber', 'info', 'memberOf', 'co', 'department', 'company', 'streetAddress', 'employeeNumber', 'employeeType', 'objectGUID', 'employeeID', 'homeDirectory', 'homeDrive', 'scriptPath', 'objectSid', 'userPrincipalName', 'url', 'msDS-SourceObjectDN', 'manager', 'extensionattribute8')

    Logger $LogFileWithPath "Querying $DomainName for user account attributes and exporting to csv file $csvFileWithPath..."
    powershell -Command {
        Param ([string]$domainControlConnector, [string]$csvOutFile, [string]$DomainName, [String[]]$domainUserProperties)
        $domain = "LDAP://$domainControlConnector"

        Write-Host "Searching Users Properties for domain $DomainNamein in AD..."
        $adDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($domain)
        $adSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($adDomain)
        $adSearcher.Filter = '(&(objectCategory=User)'
        $adSearcher.PageSize=1000
        $adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($domainUserProperties)
        $userRecords = $adSearcher.FindAll()
        Write-Host "Complete"

        # The AD results are converted to an array of hashtables.
        Write-Host "Exporting User Attributes to table..."
        $userPropertiesTable = @()
        foreach($record in $userRecords) {
            $hashUserProperty = @{}
            foreach($userProperty in $domainUserProperties){
                if ($record.Properties[$userProperty]) {
                    $hashUserProperty.$userProperty = $record.Properties[$userProperty][0]
                } else {
                    $hashUserProperty.$userProperty = $null
                }
            }
            $userPropertiesTable += New-Object PSObject -Property $hashUserProperty
        }
        Write-Host "Complete."

        $listOfBadDateValues = '9223372036854775807', '9223372036854770000', '0'
        $maxDateValue = '12/31/1600 5:00 PM'

        Write-Host "fixing table property titles and values for report"
        #$userPropertiesTable[0] = $userPropertiesTable[0] -replace 'givenname','FirstName'

        $tableFixedValues = $userPropertiesTable | % { 
            if ($_.lastLogonTimestamp) {
                $_.lastLogonTimestamp = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)).ToString('g')
            }; if (($_.AccountExpires) -and ($listOfBadDateValues -contains $_.AccountExpires)) {
                $_.AccountExpires = $null
            } else {
                if (([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpires)).ToString('g') -eq $maxDateValue) {
                    $_.AccountExpires = $null
                } Else {
                    $_.AccountExpires = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpires)).ToString('g')
                }
            }; if (($_.lastLogon) -and ($listOfBadDateValues -contains $_.lastLogon)) {
                $_.lastLogon = $null
            } else {
                if (([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon)).ToString('g') -eq $maxDateValue) {
                    $_.lastLogon = $null
                } Else {
                    $_.lastLogon = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogon)).ToString('g')
                }
            }; if (($_.pwdLastSet) -and ($listOfBadDateValues -contains $_.pwdLastSet)) {
                $_.pwdLastSet = $null
            } else {
                if (([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).ToString('g') -eq $maxDateValue) {
                    $_.pwdLastSet = $null
                } Else {
                    $_.pwdLastSet = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.pwdLastSet)).ToString('g')
                }
            };$_}
        Write-Host "Complete"

        Write-Host "Exporting table to csv file $csvOutFile"
        $tableFixedValues | Select-Object $domainUserProperties | Export-Csv $csvOutFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
        Write-Host "Complete"

        Write-Host "Changing column titles to expected format"
        $data = Get-Content $csvOutFile
        $data[0] = $data[0] -replace 'givenname', 'FirstName'
        $data[0] = $data[0] -replace 'sn', 'LastName'
        $data | Set-Content $csvOutFile -Force
        Write-Host "Complete"
        Write-Host ""


    } -args $DomainControlConnector, $csvFileWithPath, $DomainName, $domainUserProperties
}

Function Main
{
    CreateQueriedCsvDataSheet

}

Main
```

The output for the values of columns `objectGUID` and `objectSid` are printing as `System.Byte[]`. How can I get it to extract the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values *are* correct. You just need to convert them to the form you expect.

```
$stringGUID = ([guid]$binaryGUID).Guid
$stringSID  = (New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($binarySID, 0)).Value
```

[[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862181/1630171)] [[source](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/10/21/converting-binary-sid-to-string-sid.aspx)]

Comment: Thanks you are awesome! I had no idea about how to convert those two objects. I have it if I add an if condition to `$_.objectGUID` It will write the output of the numbers with `write-host $_.objectGUID`, however if I use `$_.objectGUID = $_.objectGUID).ToString()`, and then use `write-host $_.objectGUID`, it will show it as `System.Byte[]`. This tells me this is happening because the value is trying to be converted to a string upon export-csv, and that is what happens. So you are right that it needs to be converted beforehand. Thanks again for showing the conversion types.